# How to connect Postgis database with/in Remote Servers...?

Tags: geoserver, postgis-2.0

I am preparing a 'Web based map' application using 'Geoserver-Openlayers-Postgis'.

I am trying to connect my Postgis database(located at 10.50.110.11 location) with the following command from 10.40.48.22 location....

---

$host = 'localhost/10.50.110.11';
$port = '5432';
$database = 'template_postgis_20';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = 'user';

$connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
    ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password;

$link = pg_connect($connectString);
if (!$link)
{
    die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    echo "Could NOT connect POSTGRES...";
}

---

This is yielding a blank response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved..in pg.hba conf file of both servers (in my cases *.*110.11 & *.*.48.22) i have specified the connection details of the opposite server. Like @ *.*.110.11 I have specified connection info of *.*.48.22

Comment: Please edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 2):

The command should have been:

> $host = '10.50.110.11'; $port = '5432'; $database =
>   'template_postgis_20'; $user = 'postgres'; $password = 'user';

You also need to set your server to listen to connections from interfaces. To do this, change the `listen_addresses` in your `postgresql.conf` file from `127.0.0.1` to `*`.

You might also want to check your `pg_hba.conf`. See if it allows addresses other than localhost to connect.

Sources: 
[StackExchange thread on Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150738/cannot-connect-to-postgres-from-remote-host)

Comment: @ R.K...The listen_addresses in postgresql.conf is already set as '*'...

Comment: Then I guess the problem is with the value in 'host'. Updated my answer.